# Can't get S3 bucket names based on tag values

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3

In our aws account we have ~ 1000 S3 buckets and each S3 bucket has tag corresponding to application name (e.g., key=application, value=app1). I'm trying to find out how many S3 buckets a particular application owns. So, first got a list of all the S3 buckets; then iterating thru the list to match tag value of "app1". It should be pretty simple, but for some reason it's giving "AccessDenied when calling GetBucketTagging operation" error. I verified the IAM role I'm assuming has permission for GetBucketTagging

1) Got a list of s3 buckets using the credentials (IAM role I'm assuming)
2) Iterate thru the list and try to match the key, value pair of the tag ( key=application, value =application1)

## first option

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')
buckets = client.list_buckets()['Buckets']
matching_buckets = []
# tag key and value to search for
tag_key = 'application'
tag_value = 'app1'
for bucket in buckets:
    tags = client.get_bucket_tagging(Bucket=bucket['Name'])['TagSet']

    for tag in tags:
        if tag['Key'] == tag_key and tag['Value'] == tag_value:
        matching_buckets.append(bucket['Name'])
```

## 2nd option

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
app = "app1"
bucketlist = s3.list_buckets()['Buckets']
print(len(bucketlist))
bucketname = []
n=0
#iterate thru the list of {Name, CreationDate} to get all the bucket names and append to empty list

def bucket_tagging_method(b,app):
    mybucketlist = []
    bucket_tagging = s3.get_bucket_tagging(Bucket=b)
    tag_set = bucket_tagging['TagSet']
    for tag in tag_set:
        if (tag['Key'] == "application") and (tag['Value'] == app) :
            mybucketlist.append(b)
            pass
    return(mybucketlist)


while n < len(bucketlist):
    d = bucketlist[n]
    bucketname.append(d['Name'])
    n+=1

for i in bucketname:
    print(bucket_tagging_method(i,app))
```

It gives the following error

```
tags = client.get_bucket_tagging(Bucket=bucket['Name'])['TagSet']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetBucketTagging operation: Access Denied
```

Comment: how do you pass the credentials to your application after assuming the role?

Comment: I run an utility which validates my assumed role and config (under .aws folder) file gets updated accordingly

Comment: It is likely that you need to export some env variables to activate the profile if the utility creates a named profile. First find the name of this profile in .aws/credentials then export it, export AWS_PROFILE=your_profile_name", before running your python app.

Comment: it turns out some of the buckets have very restrictive bucket policies; hence bucket_tagging was throwing exception. Pls see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import boto3

boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='my_profile')
client = boto3.client('s3')
# get list of buckets this iam role can see
buckets = client.list_buckets()['Buckets']

# iterate through list of buckets looking at tags
matching_buckets = []
# tag key and value to search for
tag_key = 'app'
tag_value = 'application1'

for idx, bucket in enumerate(buckets):
#comment out following line if you don't want to see the progress
#print(f'{idx+1} of {len(buckets)} - {bucket["Name"]}')
try:
    tags = client.get_bucket_tagging(Bucket=bucket['Name'])['TagSet']
except client.exceptions.ClientError:
    continue
# iterate through tags looking for specific key
for tag in tags:
    if tag['Key'] == tag_key and tag['Value'] == tag_value:
        matching_buckets.append(bucket['Name'])

print("buckets belonging to", tag_value, "are: ", matching_buckets)
```